# Standard C++ Thread IDs - strange behavior

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

i need to create some threads on demand because i dont know before how much i need.
To 'store' the threads im using a vector `std::vector<std::thread> threads;`
every time i create a new thread i push them back on the vector: `threads.push_back(std::thread(worker));`

to store (for testing) the thread id i use the following: `double test = std::hash<std::thread::id>()(std::this_thread::get_id());`
according to the cpp-references [hash](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/id/hash), [thread::id](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/id) and [get_id](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/get_id) this should work fine.

but only with this line im getting as id always a 0 (zero)

if id add the following line below the hash line it works and i get a hashed id from the thread: `std::thread::id tid = std::this_thread::get_id();`
even i dont use `tid`

can someone explain this behavior?
im working with eclipse juno and cleaned + rebuild the project several times...i just dont get it :/

here the code:
(line by line because those format rules here are stupid -.-

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
void worker (){
    double test = std::hash<std::thread::id>()(std::this_thread::get_id());
    std::thread::id tid = std::this_thread::get_id();
    printf("%ld\n", test);
}
void joinThreads(std::thread& t)
{
    t.join();
}
int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(worker) );
    }
    std::for_each(threads.begin(),threads.end(),joinThreads);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code is added.. took a while because i always got the error for "wrong" format Oo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On x86_64 a `double` argument to `printf` would be passed in a different register to a `long` argument, so when you call `printf("%ld\n", test)` the compiler puts `test` in a floating point register and calls the function. The `printf` implementation then looks for the argument in a non-floating point register because the `"%ld"` conversion specifier tells it to expect a `long int` argument.  Because the actual argument is not in the same register as `printf` looks in, it fails to find the value.

When you add the next line it causes the value of `tid` to be in a non-floating point register, and apparently that allows `printf` to find it (but don't rely on that, it's undefined behaviour and unpredictable.)

Solution:  If you can't use `printf` correctly then don't use it at all.  Either use the right conversion specified for `double` i.e. `"%f"` or store the value in a different type, or use iostreams.

Comment: +1 Excellent explanation of what could cause the observed behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The format specifier is incorrect as `%ld` is a `long`, not a `double`, so the program has undefined behaviour. Also, the return value type of `std::hash<>::operator()` is `size_t`, not `double`. Use (type safe) `std::cout` instead:

```
auto test = std::hash<std::thread::id>()(std::this_thread::get_id());
std::cout << test << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your output is wrong. `%d` is not for `double`, it stands for *decimal*, i.e. `int`s.

What you want is

```
printf("%f\n", test);
```

Of course, none of this would have happened if you just used `std::cout` in the first place, as suggested by hmjd's answer.

Comment: %ld is in fact what i want.
in gdb the output is
`[New Thread 0x7ffff308f700 (LWP 20234)]`
the hex value is the id. if i print this with %f its not the same value?
or am im just confused?

Comment: Then why save the hash to a double in the first place? Could have just left it a `size_t`, which is the original return type of `std::hash`.

Comment: @baam, you're confused. If you pass a `double` to `printf` you have to tell it you passed a double, using `"%f"` ... it really doesn't matter if that is not "in fact what you want" (or think you want) because you're causing undefined behaviour by doing it wrong.  If you want a hex value then you don't want `"%ld"` _or_ `"%f"`, since neither of them prints a hex value!  If you can't use `printf` correctly then don't use it at all.

Comment: Hmm.. i could swear i used size_t before and i got there a zero too.
but it works now fine.. thanks :)